# Drupal Commerce Kickstart - Making Test site of Live site

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I want to do developments on my client's website but by making a clone of it. So, main website url is: `http://website.com` and the clone i am trying to create is: `http://test.website.com`.

So far i've done the following:

1. copied entire root directory into `public_html/test` dir *(with folders config,field,FirePHPCore,fontyourface,includes,js,misc,modules,scripts,sites,styles and themes)*
2. created a subdomain in cPanel for `test.website.com`
3. checked the file `settings.php` (inside `sites/default` folder) for `$base_url` but found it commented, so left it as it is unchanged.
4. copied db via phpMyAdmin and updated the new db details in `settings.php` (inside `sites/default` folder).
5. inside the table `variable`, two rows with the name `securepages_basepath` and `securepages_basepath_ssl`. Changed their values from `http://website.com` to `http://test.website.com` (using the `variable_get` and `variable_set` functions).

Now i can access `http://test.website.com` but when i click on login (from header) it takes me to `http://website.com/user` and if manually type `http://test.website.com/user` and login then it takes me to `http://website.com/users/admin` then i have to manually type in correct address `http://test.website.com/users/admin`.

And when i logout, it again takes me back to `http://website.com`.

So i want to know how can i completely make it to work on `http://test.website.com`?
Are there more variables to change?
And how i can make 100% sure that the test site is only using test and not the live site. I am afraid of messing up live website.

Please advice, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you omitted data from cache tables during your migration?

Comment: @Mołot, i forgot earlier but now i `TRUNCATED` all the cache tables but it still goes to `http://website.com/users/admin` after login, instead of staying on to the `http://test.website.com/users/admin`

Comment: Also i just noticed that whatever i am changing being on the test site admin `http://test.website.com/users/admin` it is affecting the live website! I double checked the `settings.php` file and i have test db info set there and not the live one. Any help?

Comment: just another weird thing i am noticing, i.e. if i put a wrong db details inside the `public_html/test/sites/default/settings.php` file and hits the site but it still works. It is showing that its loading content from `http://test.website.com/` but i think its loading configuration from the live website.

Comment: ok, after a lot of digging and searching all over google, i got my problem fixed by setting off the `secure pages`. Since it was not allowing me to do that due to the urls being changed after login, so i had to do it manually from mysql db under `variable` table and `securepages_enable` field, it was in blob so i downloaded the blob first and then changed the value in it from `1` to `0` and uploaded it back using `phpMyAdmin`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by disabling the secure pages from inside the mysql database. It was inside `variable` table and `securepages_enable` field. It was in blob so i had to download the blob first and opened it in notepad and changed the value inside it from `1` to `0` and then uploaded it back by updating the `securepages_enable` field.

I had to do this because after logging in from my test url, the urls were redirecting back to the live website, so whatever change i was making, it was all affecting the live site.

Hope this helps to someone with similar case. Thanks!